# Printf number length

Tags: formatting, numbers, printf, osx-mavericks, substr

I'm trying to get printf to diplay number of a constant length (in characters) in OS X Terminal. So if I specify three character length, then the number will be 
I'd like to achieve this:

```
100.4125 -> 100
1.5131   -> 1.51
59.9159  -> 59.9
```

print substr(0,4) would nearly achieve this, but I would be left with a decimal pointer after the 100.

Comment: OSX Mavericks. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the specifier g or G will format to significant digits. The following example will format to 3 significant figures.

```
printf("ans: %.3g", 100.4125)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! Didn't know what terms to use for searching.